# Delete output files from folder SPSS Modeller

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

I am outputting/exporting results to an excel file using the Excel Export node.
I would like to delete or overwrite any old existing files in that folder.
Can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, it is actually one of the options in the same node: 
[image: Excel Output node]

Insert into existing file. Content is replaced beginning at the cell designated by the Start in cell field. Other cells in the spreadsheet are left with their original content.